# How to increase the file size limit for media uploads?

Tags: wp-admin, media, uploads

How can I change the Maximum upload file size? I would like to be able to upload 10Mb at a time.

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is due to the PHP limitations on file size uploads. If you have access to your php.ini file, you can modify the following lines:

```
upload_max_filesize = 10M
post_max_size = 10M
max_execution_time = 300
```

If you don't have access to the php.ini file (such as a hosting situation), you may need to contact your webhost and see if they will increase it for you. I have also seen users create a php.ini file with just these values and place it in the file where WordPress is installed. If your PHP instance allows for "inherited configurations" it will allow these local settings to override the global.

The other solution would be to add the code dynamically into WordPress to make this change for you. [This article](http://simplercomputing.net/2009/02/13/fix-php-max-upload-size-wordpress/) has a nice way of doing it through a "plugin". I've seen dubious results from this approach (some report success, some report no success) so I can't say for sure if it will work for you.

Comment: Thanks a ton! I am new to Wordpress and PHP so this was very helpful. Just a note for anyone else out there, if you're running on IIS, you'll need to restart IIS after editing your php.ini file.

Comment: at alast a solution for this stupid problem... thank you...

Comment: `post_max_size = 10M
max_execution_time = 300` is not needed in this case.

Comment: post_max_size is needed, actually, since both that and the upload parameter control the max upload size.

Comment: I had to also restart php with `sudo systemctl restart php7.2-fpm`

Comment: Um.. but where is this `php.ini` file usually located?

Answer (score 3):

I had the issue where I couldn't update/add to the php.ini file. I ended up adding the following lines to my .htaccess file to change the upload size:

```
 php_value upload_max_filesize 5M
 php_value post_max_size 5M
 php_value max_execution_time 200
 php_value max_input_time 200
```

That changes the upload limit to 5, and allows extends the timeout time while uploading larger files.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me. I just went into cpanel /file manager and created a new php.ini file. Then i entered the text below:
upload_max_filesize = 10M
post_max_size = 10M
max_execution_time = 300

Works 100%

Just put the php.ini file in the wp-admin directory

Answer (score 2):

Somehow I had to create a php.ini file which I uploaded to the wp-admin directory but I also had to add the memory_limit = 32M line. Without that line, the limit is not increased in in Wordpress 3.3.1

```
memory_limit = 32M
upload_max_filesize = 16M
post_max_size = 16M
max_execution_time = 300
```

Answer (score 1):

If the above solutions are not working, then you can go with this .only you have to find the php.ini file in /etc or root folder.

Step 1:

Find php.ini file in /etc folder or / folder by running below cmd:

```
grep -rl "post_max_size" | xargs ls -lrth
```

Here I have used the post_max_size keyword to search the "php.ini" file in /etc folder ,but in some systems you can find this on /var/www/html or /var/www/wordpress folders.

We have multiple posts on the internet as if the php.ini file is not present in the WordPress folder then you can create but in my case that doesn't work.

Step 2:

Edit the php.ini file and change the value like this.

```
post_max_size = 100M   
upload_max_filesize = 100M
```

In the above, you can set any value as per your requirement.

Step 3:

Restart the httpd or Nginx or apache and PHP service, or as per setup, you can restart the web service.

For me httpd and php-fpm service restart worked in centos 8:

```
service httpd restart
service php-fpm restart
```