# Creating a podcast directory site - how to allow user to upload "large" files?

Tags: uploads, user-access, podcasting

I wish to create a podcast directory site.  For which, I'd like the users of my site to be able to upload audio files which are "large" (e.g: more then 2 or 8 MB), and to make that upload "easily" go to the correct field in a relevant plugin (such as "podcasting")

Any suggestions will be welcomed.

Comment: We already have a question on [increasing the upload file size](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2823/how-to-increase-the-file-size-limit-for-media-uploads), so this question can focus on the other aspects. Do you require all files to be hosted on your site, or are suggestions to use SoundCloud or other providers welcome too?

Comment: One thing to anticipate is the limitation of browser uploads, connection speeds, etc. It's something I ran into with a DJ site. Depending on user connection speed, etc, browser connections will get dropped. FTP is the solution really. For browser based uploads, depending on host and connection, anything over about 60MB or so is very unpredictable through a browser interface

Comment: Kaiser - I'm on 98% acceptance now.   Jan - I don't have to have the files hosted, only to have a comfortable way for users to upload audios.   Rev - I agree with your points, I wonder if there is any browser interface solution that I may not have heard about.  Thanks all 3 of you for answering...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to add to what other have said, beyond changing your php.ini settings, upload size is limited mainly by the browser/connection. There are more reliable browser bases solutions that use java/flash or a combination of tech that allow for uploads reliably up to 100MB.

1. http://www.plupload.com/
2. http://www.swfupload.org/
3. http://www.uploadify.com/
4. http://jumploader.com/

Comment: Thanks Wyck, that is great.  Do you know of any of them easily integrating to WordPress?

Comment: Yes plupload already has a WP plugin, http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wplupload/ and so does uploadify, http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/uploadify/. You should have a look at the rest http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tags/upload